# Actionscript 3.0: SharedObject.flush write/storage mechanics

Tags: flash, actionscript, shared-objects

Can anyone explain a bit. If i'm using using flush it overwrites existing file with completely new?

For example i had something written in SharedObject before and now i changed 1 character and flushing again, it will write all data or just the one i have changed?

What storage mechanisms are used? It's just serialized string or there is some storage mechanism implemented?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `flush()`, I think it'll write all the data to disk. But it could just write the modified bits - depends on the implementation (it's not part of the API).

`SharedObject` uses Action Message Format (AMF3).

See the `objectEncoding` property:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#objectEncoding

Comment: Another client can read while second writes something to it? And as i understand. SharedObject just read file once, if i don't want to overwrite some data possibly written by another client, i should read shared storage contents again, before writing something?

Comment: @Beck Indeed, another client can write to it while you're still working with it, and then when you `flush()` you overwrite the other's changes. Classic problem.